# Using composer installed library, class not found error

Tags: php, linux, composer-php, autoload

I used composer to download a php bitcoin library to play around with. https://github.com/phramz/php-bitcoin-api
This one specifically.

Anyways, everytime I try to use the library with

```
use Phramz\Bitcoin\Api\Connection\BuzzConnection;
use Phramz\Bitcoin\Api\BitcoindClient;
```

I get

> Interface 'Phramz\Bitcoin\Api\Client' not found in
>   /root/vendor/phramz/php-bitcoin-api/src/Phramz/Bitcoin/Api/BitcoindClient.php

whenever I try to run any test code. I really want to play around with this library but Im sort of a newbie php programmer and this is frustrating me. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you require vendor/autoload.php as described in [Composer documentation](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading).

If Composer's vendor directory is not located in the current directory you'll need to use an absolute path or something like:

```
<?php
require_once(__DIR__."/../../vendor/autoload.php");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the kind of issue when I installed a new lib, and i just deployed the new lib to server only as I was new to PHP, it took me hours to figure out that the `vendor/composer` folder is updated when we install a new lib.

So if your server doesn't support `composer install` , upload the whole `vendor` folder to your server is the way.